# How to set a crontab job with some linux commands?

Tags: linux, cron

I want to execute some commands in a crontab job (in a Virtual Server), like this:

```
$ mysqldump --opt --user=root --password=xxxxx mysqldb1>mysqldb1.sql
$ mysqldump --opt --user=root --password=xxxxx mysqldb2>mysqldb2.sql
$ tar czvf site1.tar.gz /var/www/site1
$ tar czvf site2.tar.gz /var/www/site2
```

and also I want to upload these files to my computer.

```
$ scp mysqldb1.sql root@myIP:/home/myuser/backups
$ scp mysqldb2.sql root@myIP:/home/myuser/backups
$ scp site1.tar.gz root@myIP:/home/myuser/backups
$ scp site2.tar.gz root@myIP:/home/myuser/backups
```

Could I execute a script with all these commands every *x* time in a crontab job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can create a shell script with the above commands and run the shell script every x time with cronjob with the following command.

Say you created a shell script say backup.sh with your required commands and then you can create a cronjob using crontab -e

- - - - - sh /home/backup.sh

:wq to save and exit.
The cronjob would be saved the first * refers to minute, * refers to hour, * refers to day of the month, * refers to the month, * refers to the day of the week.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok

Comment: How should be the backup.sh file so? `scp` doesn't work if I type it in my VPS, it tells me `timeout error`. What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you able to run scp on terminal, you might need to do a ssh authentication less authorization to use it with scp in shell script or use sshpass -p 'password' scp user1@xxx.xxx.x.5:sys_config /var/www/dev/, whatever commands you are typing in console put those commands in backup.sh simple and then put it in cronjob

Comment: It works. Except the scp command. I think it must be a ssh issue. I'm trying to solve it.